# Display data on Win phone 8 UI using WCF service

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-8

I am trying to display some data from a webservice (which i know works) on a Win 8 phone UI but having some problems in trying to change the default app to one that caters for my requirements. My code

```
Private m_Cust As ObservableCollection(Of CustomerMobileApp.CustomerWebService.Customer)

Public Sub LoadData()
    Dim CustServ As New CustomerWebService.CustomerClient

    AddHandler CustServ.GetCustomersCompleted, AddressOf CustomersCompleted
    CustServ.GetCustomersAsync()

    IsDataLoaded = True
End Sub

Private Sub CustomersCompleted(sender As Object, e As CustomerWebService.GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs)
    m_Cust = e.Result
End Sub
```

This code shows m_Cust with data when i look at it in debug mode. The problem is no data is displayed on the phone UI. Looking back at the demo app that works, it has the following declaration

```
Public Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemSomething)
```

This is then added to the LoadData method to add a new item i.e. Items.Add(New ItemSomething("Value 1"))

However i cant do this in the above code as i get an error *"'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of MobileApp.CustomerWebService.Customer)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of MobileApp.ItemCustomer)'."*

ItemCustomer is the class that i created under the ViewModel folder for the MobileApp and Customer is the class that is part of the Web service.

I've spent some time on this and not really sure what to do as i know where the problem is but dont know how to resolve or how to do it properly as i cant find any working examples.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

The types have to be the same. If your using `Entity Framework` on the `Web Service` you return the `EF` models. If you don't use `EF` then use make a `Composite Type` (in your case - since they are complex) on the `Web Service` and return those. You may have to build your `itemSomething` object by looping thru the `e.Result`.

Composite Type:

```
Public Class SomeType
 Public Property Foo As Integer
 Public Property Fubar As String
End Class
```

It is just a way to pass multiple values from the service.